# What's the name for the property for which $x + x = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x = 0$?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

I have a set $\mathbb{S}$ for which I have defined an operation: addition ($+ : \mathbb{S} \times \mathbb{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}$). The structure $(\mathbb{S}, +)$ is a group.

I have shown that if $x + x = 0$, then $x$ is not necessarily $0$ (where $x \in \mathbb{S}$ and $0$ is the identity element).

Clearly, my $+$ operator is lacking a property. How is this property called?

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion-free_abelian_group . I don't think that such a property has a name: simply one could say that "there exist an element of order $2$".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to say that $(\mathbb{S}, +)$ [does not have $2$-torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_subgroup#p-power_torsion_subgroups), or perhaps that it is [$2$-torsion-free](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/2-torsion-free_group).

Comment: Although strictly speaking, he has found that $(\mathbb S, +)$ *does* have $2$-torsion, or is *lacking* $2$-torsion-freeness.

Comment: @k.stm Sure, but the question is "What's the name for the property for which $x + x = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x = 0$?"

Comment: AndreasCaranti. Ah okay. I still think your answer is phrased confusingly. Perhaps it’s better to say “You might say that a group with such a property …, so $(\mathbb S, +)$ does not …” or so. Whatever, though, I didn’t see the title question.

Answer (score 2):

An element $x$ such that $x+x=0$ is called an involution. See here under the "group theory" heading:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)

This is the opposite of the property you describe, and seems to be the rarer case. An operation under which no element has order 2 could perhaps be called "involution-free"

Answer (score 2):

If your set $\mathbb{S}$ is a ring, such property perhaps could be stated as : $characteristic(\mathbb{S})\not=2$

[wikipedia: Characteristic (algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra))

Answer (score 0):

In a group $G$ ,written multiplicatively,with identity element $1$: For $x\in G,$ if $x^n=1$ for some positive integer $n,$ then the least such $n$ is called the order of $x$ (or the order of $x$ in $G$), sometimes written $[x]=n.$ The order need not exist. For example in the additive group of Reals, only the identity $0$ has an order : $[0]=1.$  You can say, for your Q, that no member of $S$ has order $2.$